# How to change to a different markup tool in Autodesk Viewer APIs Markup Extension

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I've been playing with [Autodesk Viewer API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/). I've got the Markup-extension loaded and I can draw Arrows with it. But I can't figure out how to change the tool to Rectangle or something else.

I've followed [this tutorial](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/tutorial-feature_markup.html) but I don't know if that's up to date. There's a [releated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42554749/drawing-2d-svg-markups-using-markupcore/42556625#42556625) saying that the apis have changed somehow.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well right after asking this I checked the [source](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.js) for the Markup-extension and comment there for changeEditMode says

> Applicable only while in [Edit Mode]

My mistake was that I was trying to change tool mode before entering editMode.

So this works.

```
var markup = _viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore");
var modeRect = new Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.Markups.Core.EditModeRectangle(markup);

markup.enterEditMode();
markup.changeEditMode(modeRect);

//markup.leaveEditMode();
```

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear you found the solution yourself. Let us know if you need anything else in a new question.